# How can I make cone look more like light?

Tags: light, lighting

[image]

I use cones to make it look like a spotlight.

Spotlight on the left
On the right is the cone.

I would like to add a smear effect or something else to make it look a little more like a spotlight.

Comment: hello, do you have a picture that would show the kind of effect you are looking for?

Comment: Hello @moonboots 

There is no effect I have seen, but I would like the exterior of the cone to be slightly blurred.

like that :)

https://www.vectorstock.com/royalty-free-vector/spotlight-vector-16308346

Comment: Is this for Cycles or Eevee? In contrary to Eevee, Cycles allows a node setup for lights.

Comment: @Blunder this is Cycles!

Comment: I believe cycles can render volumetric lights.

Answer (score 3):

A trick that you can use to create a blurred light beam, whether you are in Cycles or Eevee, is the *Layer Weight* node : Mix an *Emission* with a *Transparent*, use a *Layer Weight* (*Facing* output) as factor, play with the *Blend* factor:

[image]

*Layer Weight* considers the direction of your normals, in my setup, if the normals are perpendicular to the view, the faces will appear transparent.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
However, the light has to be projected from the back, so I made the cone translucent like in my photo.
Can't you give such an effect in this state?

I'm new to Blender, so I don't know much about Node. Sorry.

Comment: what do you mean "from the back"? Actually the trick I give can be used in combination with other nodes to get closer to what you want

Comment: Another object should be visible behind the cone :)

Comment: you can do it with my solution, you can add transparency with another Mix Shader and a Transparent node etc

Comment: Thank you for the advice ! 
I will try :)