# How to create a similar light beam?

Tags: lighting

I'm trying to create a similar scene (1st pic) but I can't get such smooth light edges and beautiful fadeout, my lights look pretty ugly (2nd pic)
[image: Picture]
[image: My]

Comment: maybe try Layer Weight? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227887/how-can-i-make-cone-look-more-like-light

Comment: Easiest way to do it would be to create 3 very long this spot lights with same color and diffrent rotation