# I want to get this godray effect while in animation. is that possible?

Tags: rendering, animation, compositing-nodes, effects

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Akb4P71KL0s

In this video, they showing us godray effect using Volumetric Fog. in blender i can`t get only that effect.

I was tested two ways to get that effect.

first way is placing volumetric object and placing light to get that effect but, using this method is causing fog effect, the scene is looks so foggy. i don`t want that, i just want god ray only.

second way is using compositing. there`s sun beams node to achieve that effect however, my current scene is for animation so, animating sunbeams according to match the real sun position is so hard.

is there any way to achieve that effect without any changes in my scene?

If my grammar is weird, I'm sorry I'm not an English speaker.

Comment: maybe try this trick with Layer Weight? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227887/how-can-i-make-cone-look-more-like-light

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: If you want to you can create an object that matches the sun beam roughly, then give the cube volume scatter on a low density