# Recreating lightsaber shaders from a game

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

This is a strange issue that may require some context. I work with ripped models from an old iOS game, Infinity Blade, and I have not run into many issues as most of its shading work is just simple textures. However, the game includes some references to Star Wars with its lightsabers and these things have been stumping me for years.
From everything I have tried, there are two different issues that I reach a dead end with depending on the rendering engine used. When using Eevee, its a problem of backfacing overlapping

[image: The purple outline from the saber behind the red is shown on top]

And when Cycles is used, the polygons from the "glow" of the sabers are shown, more noticeably with the black saber.

[image: A purple line runs through the middle of the black saber]

Neither of these are ideal and I'm completely at a loss what else to try. Any help at all is appreciated and I will do my best to answer any questions.

Comment: Hello, have you tried with the Layer Weight node? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227887/how-can-i-make-cone-look-more-like-light

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to help much due to the saber's reliance on alpha textures and blending, at least from what I believe.