# Transparency using layer weight and colorRamp

Tags: transparency, color, shader-nodes

I am trying to create a colorful light beam similar to a laser (with a gradient in the middle) using ColorRamp, Mix Shader and Layer Weight.

[image]

I would like to make this beam as much as possible transparent so that it is still possible to clearly see the structure below, but I would like to keep this nice gradient of the light and the Glare effect I have added in Compositing.

I have already added a Transparent BSDF node and tried with the Math node with division, but the problem is that - when I add it after the ColorRamp - all the alpha values are divided accordingly and I loose this gradient effect in the final rendered image.

[image]

Comment: maybe try my answer here? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227887/how-can-i-make-cone-look-more-like-light

Comment: Hello, thanks for the suggestions, but if you look at my screenshot I am already doing that.

Comment: have you given a Subdivision Surface to your object and shaded smooth?

Comment: Now I have done this both on the cone and on the cube and the gradient has become much more focused in the middle rather than along the length of the beam. The problem is also that - if I want to see the Glare effect - the Emission strength has to be very high but this masks almost completely the shape of the object in the beam

Comment: maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/