# Make Volumes only visible when light overlapps it

Tags: volumetrics

I wanted to know if there is a way of telling blender that volume objects should only show the volume, the fog and stuff when it is overlapping with a light source. I was trying to replicate the Youtube tutorials on how to make Volumetric light, but it does not really do the trick for me. I don't want to have the fog EVERYWHERE inside the cube, but only when where for an example a light cone is shining.

[image: With Lights]

[image: Without Lights]

**Answer**: Okay, thanks to the comments I was capable to find the problem, it was the emission property of the principled volume in the shading editor for the volume material that is set on the volume cube. I just set it to 0, and it gives me the desired effect now.

Comment: What are your settings in _Light Paths_ > _Max Bounces_ > _Volume_? And do you only have spotlights in the scene which should show the fog or is there a sunlight or other environment lighting?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann What are your recommended settings to get it to work how I want it? There is only one spotlight, one cube with a volume material. I don't know where the light paths setting is you mentioned.

Comment: In the _Render Properties_ you will find _Light Paths_ > _Max Bounces_ and then _Volume_. If the bounces value for _Volume_ is larger than 0, light will be scattered inside the cube and therefore also be visible outside of the spotlight's cone. Values ≥ 1 will be more realistic for a room filled with fog, but will also take more time to render and produce your undesired fog "everywhere".

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thank you for the information. However, I just tried both 0 and 1 and in both cases the fog is everywhere where the volume cube is. To say, the one with the volume material.

Comment: That cannot be actually with bounces 0 if there is no other light source. Because the light from the spot won't reach the fog in the rest of the cube. You're sure there is nothing else? When you turn off the spotlight it's absolutely black? No light coming from the world?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I added two pictures to the main post, so you can see it for yourself.

Comment: The last image is without any light source? Then the fog should be black, not glowing... would you mind showing your fog material? Looks like you've got some emission in the fog itself.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann ... that was actually the solution. Thank you allot for pointing that out for me. The emission property of the principled volume was set on 0.1 or something. I just set it to 0 And now it works. The volume is only there where the light shines. Thank you allot. You are a great help.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the color of the Principled Volume almost to black and the Absorption Color to full white I think you will get that effect.[image]

Comment: That's not how it works. I mean, maybe this is the desired result, but simply try two different settings in the _Principled Volume_ shader: **1:** _Color_ to dark grey like V = 0.01, _Density_ to 1 and _Absorption Color_ to full white at V = 1. Compare it to **2:** _Color_ full white at V = 1, _Density_ to 0.01, _Absorption Color_ black, V = 0. The result will look exactly the same. With color white and density 0.01 you can also set the absorption to white, it still looks the same. What makes the fog visible is if you also have a sun or environment light or the Light Paths Volume bounces > 0.

Comment: Just for a short explanation: all fog which is visible in the air comes from scattered light, whereas the _Absorption Color_ manipulates (as the name suggests) the light absorption. Light that gets absorbed doesn't show up in the camera as visible fog in the air. That's why in your solution you have to leave the _Color_ at dark grey and cannot turn it all the way down to black. Black means no scattering, so no visible fog, no matter which _Absorption Color_ you choose.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a cone, give it volumetrics, and give it the exact same shape as the light spot cone:

[image]

Another trick would be to use a cone with *Emission* and *Transparent* node and a *Layer Weight* node as factor, see [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227887/how-can-i-make-cone-look-more-like-light).

Comment: That's a good idea! And if you want real volumetrics with objects throwing shadows in the fog definitely to be preferred over the trick you've linked to. Then combine the cone with _Copy Location_ and _Copy Rotation_ constraints targeting the spotlight and you can even reposition the light easily.

Comment: or simply parent the one to the other?

Comment: Haha, of course :) I just used constraints because I already had the light in a certain position and angle so parenting at this constellation made no sense :D The only thing with this method which has to be kept in mind: if you've set the spotlight to a soft edge, this gets a sharp outline from the cone if you set the volume bounces to a value greater than 0.